# Timing Belt Tension VIDEO

Tags: honda, accord, timing-belt

too loose?

https://goo.gl/photos/pV8EuQz3SHTkoGN87

2000 Honda Accord LX 110,000 miles

Answer (score 1):

Nope, looks fine.

It wouldn't harm to tighten up a hair if you can do so simply, but it looks fine to me.  It doesn't look in imminent risk of slipping.